# Get Selected Items in dynamic checkbox list WPF C#

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mvvm, binding, bind

In my viewmodel, I have a Collection of Categories (a Category has an id and a name).
I managed to dynamically display my list of checkboxes in my view. Thoses checkboxes are used to filter some data (displaying only data that have the checked categories).
How can I get the checked categories?

```
<ListBox x:Name="listViewCategories" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems}" BorderBrush="Transparent" SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                      Margin="3"
                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And here is my model

```
private ObservableCollection<Category> _selectedItems = new();
public ObservableCollection<Category> SelectedItems
{
    get => _selectedItems;
    set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItems, value, () => Console.WriteLine("Click"));
}
```

I have tried a lot of things.

- creating a property in Category 'IsChecked' and bind IsChecked of the checkbok to that property (Category implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) but it doesn't work.
- Binding  'IsChecked' of the checkbox to the IsSelected property of the ListBoxItem but my SelectedItems collection is never notified of any changement.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What can you see in your Output window when you bind to your models `IsChecked`?

Comment: Nothing. It updates the property IsCkecked but doesn't notify the ObservableCollection so it doesn't print "Click"

Comment: It won't be updating the collection since its bound to a model. Only when you create a new collection the "Click" will be printed. You need to pick up an event within observable collection that updates items, then you will know when an item is updated. hope this makes sense

Comment: Yeah I figured... So my question is how can I get my list of checked/unchecked categories then...  (Thanks anyway)

Comment: Well if you have a button in your UI then on command execute you can loop through your categories like this: `SelectedItems.Where(i => i.IsChecked);` then you have all selected categories and you can apply your filter.

Comment: There is no button. They (my teachers don't want us to add one). It has to be dynamic, the filter should be applied when we click on a checkbox...
The only buttons I have are "check all" and "check none" (but that's for something else).
I tried to add a method by doing this
Check="addCategory_click"
Uncheck="removeCategory_click"
But then, my are buttons "check all" and "check none" don't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are multiple ways to approach this. Down below you find my way.

I would suggest using the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf.dll` which can be downloaded via Nuget. This contains `<Interaction.Triggers>` which can be used to map a event to an command.
I have also included a listview to show the selected categories.
See the following code.

This is the application XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ApplicationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="listViewCategories" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"  BorderBrush="Transparent" SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                                  Margin="3"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                     >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.(local:ApplicationViewModel.CheckedCommand)}"
                                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.(local:ApplicationViewModel.UnCheckedCommand)}"
                                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Selected Categories" />
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategories}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    
</Grid>
```

This is my category class:

```
  public class Category


{
    
    private string id;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
   

    }
}
```

This is my viewmodel class:

```
 public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>
        {
            new Category{ID="1",Name="Apple"},
            new Category{ID="2",Name="Banana"},
            new Category{ID="2",Name="Orange"},

        };
        SelectedCategories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
        
    }

 

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Category> SelectedCategories { get; set; } = new();



    private ICommand _checkedCommand;
    public ICommand CheckedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_checkedCommand == null)
            {
                _checkedCommand = new RelayCommand(param =>
                {
                    var category = param as Category;
                    this.SelectedCategories.Add(category);
                });

            }
            return _checkedCommand;
        }
    }

    private ICommand _unCheckedCommand;
    public ICommand UnCheckedCommand {
        get
        {
            if(_unCheckedCommand == null)
            {
                _unCheckedCommand = new RelayCommand(param => {

                    var category = param as Category;
                    this.SelectedCategories.Remove(category);
                });
            }
            return _unCheckedCommand;
        }
    }



}
```

I also implemented a class `RelayCommand` which was easy and pretty straight forward but most of the MVVM-Frameworks have something like this already in store.

this is the RelayCommand Class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }
    
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if(_execute !=null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }
    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

So basically I had a method AddCategory and RemoveCategory (inline in this case as lambda but you get the point) and bound this via EventToCommand to the viewmodel.

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as answered. If you need anything else feel free to update you question